# DB2 - Limit fetched rows in table by selecting row count from other table

Tags: sql, select, count, db2, limit

I am trying to get row count in Table_A, save it in a variable and fetch the same row count in Table_B.

```
CREATE VARIABLE myvar INTEGER;
SET myvar = (SELECT count (*) FROM Table_A)

SELECT * from Table_B
fetch first {mywar} rows ONLY

DROP VARIABLE myvar;
```

How can I achieve this in DB2? Is it better in this case to use Limit? Can this be achieved without using variables?

Comment: Consider using dynamic SQL. You also should edit your question to specify the Db2-server platform and version/fixpack ,  and also which tool submits the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could do e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS RN from Table_B)
WHERE RN <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table_A)
```